# IotHub Direct Method Quota LImi

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

In the documentation theres a quota which states following:

Direct methods  160KB/sec/unit

I am asking me wether the quota is per iothub or per device. 
What is the unit here?

Answer (score 0):

An IoT Hub can have multiple 'units' within the same tier. The pricing page describes a unit as:

> IoT Hub unit represents a single IoT Hub. Number of units depends on
>   number of messages required for your IoT solution. For example, each
>   unit of S1 or B1 IoT Hub can handle 400,000 messages a day.

Within your IoT Hub tier (Basic and up) you can have up to 200 units. The [Quotas and throttling paragraph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-quotas-throttling#quotas-and-throttling) of the documentation describes a unit's role in quota questions.